# Cartoon style map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Our university has had an agency create a [very pretty printed map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nuHC.jpg)* for a special purpose.

In the early stages of the project, I suggested that they make the map in true proportions, and in vector format, so that a digital version might be more easily made in future. The future is looming, and it's looking like I'm going to have to come up with something!

I've begun toying with ways of doing this. One option is to make a suitable base layer and add the buildings as individual svg files - it sounds like a LOT of work.

I wondered if anyone had suggestions about how I should approach this. Is mapbox even the right tool?

* apparently, I don't have the 'reputation' required to embed an image!

Answer (score 2):

There have been a number of impressive cartonish and artistically stylized maps made with Mapbox GL JS and Mapbox Studio Classic.

- https://www.mapbox.com/blog/pencil-drawn-style/
- http://dessine-moi-une-ville.makina-corpus.net/#15/43.5933/1.4514
- http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/aj.Sketchy2/page.html#6/33.962/-6.405
- https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/#map-7
- https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/#map-20

> I've begun toying with ways of doing this. One option is to make a suitable base layer and add the buildings as individual svg files - it sounds like a LOT of work.

This sounds like the one good way to go about adding individual building illustrations. Other options include using one or many [image sources](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-image).

Good luck! Can't wait to see what you make!

Comment: Holey moley! they are amazing!! Whether or not I get to try any of this will depend on the budget allocation - I have my fingers crossed!

Meantime, I have a question about adding SVG as an 'icon' on a feature. I ran a test - scaling the SVG with the map, and was surprised to see the svg looking soft and anti aliased, as if it were a raster graphic. Why do they not scale as vectors? http://go.unimelb.edu.au/r3ba

Comment: GL JS does not support vector image rendering. Implementing a SVG renderer in WebGL is a big challenge.